# Why does $n!$ grow faster than $2^{n \log n}$

Tags: combinatorics

According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20%28n!%29%20/%20%282%5E%28n%2alog%28n%29%29%29) the following holds:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!}{2^{n \log_2 n}} = \infty$$

However, by the following argumentation I would expect the limit to approach 0 (or at least not infinity).

- $n!$ counts the number of permutations of $n$ elements, that is $|S_n| = n!$
- $S_n$ is a subset of the set of all functions with the signature $f : [n] \rightarrow [n]$
- We can give a one-to-one correspondence between every function $f : [n] \rightarrow [n] $ and the set of all $n \log_2 n$ long bitstrings
- There exist $2^{n \log_2 n}$ different bitstrings of length $n \log_2 n$
- Therefore for all $n$ it must hold that
  $$ n! \leq 2^{n \log_2 n}$$

From the last point it directly follows that the above limit shouldn't exceed 1.

Where is the flaw in this argumentation?

Comment: You asked WA about $n!/2^{n \log n}$, not $n!/2^{n \log_2 n}$, hence WA is right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct. $$2^{n\log_2 n}=n^n \ge n!$$

However what you entered into alpha was $$2^{n\ln n}=2^{n\ln 2 \log_2 n}=n^{n\ln 2}=(n^n)^{\ln 2}$$

---

More info.  By [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n!e^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}n^n}=1$$
In other words, $$n!\sim \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}n^n}{e^n}$$
Hence $$\frac{n!}{(n^n)^\alpha}\sim \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}}{e^n}(n^n)^{1-\alpha}$$
This limit (as $n\to \infty$) is $\infty$ for $\alpha<1$, and $0$ for $\alpha\ge 1$.  In the case in question $\alpha=\ln 2\approx 0.69$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that wolfram alpha assumes base $e$. Your reasoning is correct. Note that $$2^{n\log_{2}n}=2{log_2{n^n}=n^n}$$

Try this and WA replies correctly. Just don't question WA.